# Resolving references across cells when using Jupyter notebook in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I just started using Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm.

It seems that the code inspection does not properly resolve references across the cells in the notebook.

For example, if the first cell contains

```
import numpy as np
```

and the second cell then uses a numpy function, e.g.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

then both the import statement and the call to np.array are highlighted by the code inspector with an "Unused import" and "unresolved reference" message respectively.

Is this intended? Is there a way to make the inspection work across cells?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using a remote interpreter, and was wondering if it was related.  The cells run fine, but command completion, docs, etc. don't work unless the import is in the same cell.